# SortedList not found for support v7

Tags: android, sortedlist, android-appcompat

I found the below error while upgrading the app.

```
error: cannot access SortedList class file for android.support.v7.util.SortedList not found
```

Comment: Do you have the right Gradle dependencies?  [See here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList).

Comment: what did u upgrade?

Comment: i am upgrading this - classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'